# Table Partition Function - 2008

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have created a new database with a secondary file as fallows:

```
CREATE DATABASE XYZ_Dimensions_DW
ON PRIMARY
(NAME='DBForPartitioning_1',
FILENAME=
'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\XYZ_Dimensions_DW_1.mdf',
SIZE = 20,
MAXSIZE=1048576,
FILEGROWTH=20 ),
FILEGROUP FG3
(NAME = 'DBForPartitioning_2',
FILENAME =
'F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\XYZ_Dimensions_DW_2.ndf',
SIZE = 20,
MAXSIZE=1048576,
FILEGROWTH=20 )
GO
```

And I have created partition function as fallows:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION salesYearPartitions (int)
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (5208);

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME salesPartitionScheme
AS PARTITION salesYearPartitions
TO ([PRIMARY], FG )
```

After this I have archived all the data as per the partitions and now sendoray file having 1 million records.

```
enter code here
```

Here, my question is how to alter my partition funcation from 5208 to 5000. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION partition_function_name()
{ 
    SPLIT RANGE ( boundary_value )
  | MERGE RANGE ( boundary_value ) 
} [ ; ]
```

more here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186307.aspx

Comment: Hi Lan, Thanks for your reply...Can you please guide me how to use the partition function with the above scenario with 5000. Appreciates your help...

Comment: Hi..Just want to confirm below script is correct    alter partition function salesyearpartions () merge range (5000). Please help me

Comment: First split the partition upt to 5208 to two so there is one for upto 5000 and one from above 5000 to 5208. Then merge the 5208 range into its higher partition

Answer (score 0):

You have to commands to manage partition boundaries: `SPLIT` a partition and `MERGE` two adjacent partitions. To change your boundary you have 2 options:

1. If you have no data, then

   ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION partition_function_name() MERGE RANGE 5208
   ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION partition_function_name() SPLIT RANGE 5000
2. If you have significant amount of data loaded then doing it other way will be faster:

   ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION partition_function_name() SPLIT RANGE 5000
   ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION partition_function_name() MERGE RANGE 5208

The reason for the difference is that when you split partition SQL Server reads and separates all data in the partition being split. So instead of splitting full data set it will split only half og the populated data set.